# Is there a good sofware for writing mathematical notation?

Tags: math-software

To make mathematical annotations on the computer I use Notepad, but Notepad has neither a formula editor nor almost any editor, so it very quickly starts to get harder to read equations. The other pieces of software I have seen were robust, as Evernote. For Notepad, I press two buttons, type “notepad”, press enter, and I have a simple and fast notepad, whose files I can save easily, differently of Evernote. Just a Notepad with formula editor would be great...

Hence, my question: is there any software good for annotating stuff? By the way, I know it is just extreme convenience and even LaTeX would suffice.

Comment: I don't know if this type of question is allowed.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/

Comment: @user1551, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $\LaTeX$ will suffice and you are willing to learn it, use it. You can learn most of the math syntax right here on this site from a mathjax tutorial. Texlive is a good application to download. Overleaf does TeX in the cloud for you.

Comment: Ethan, I shall try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac,
I use Macdown:

https://macdown.uranusjr.com/

Another one
that is available for Mac,
Windows, and Linux
is Haroopad:

http://pad.haroopress.com/user.html

Comment: Marty, thanks for answering. I tried Haroopad, and I was unable to use it because of the bugs. I mean it literally,